# Merge diffrent shaped dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, join, merge

Merge DF1 and DF2 on Company_url however the result should look like DF3

[image: DF1]

[image: DF2]

[image: DF3]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with your sample data as text, not as images or links, and _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research. This will help us to offer specific answers.

Comment: For example, `set_index` and `transpose` seem useful here